# kineticjs regular polygon setFillPatternImage alignment issue

Tags: image, polygon, kineticjs, fill, polyfills

I am using a kineticjs regular polygon (a hexagon in this case) and I am filling it with an image using  setFillPatternImage. This is working. I'm creating a dynamic implementation so I need to scale the source image depending on the current size of the polygon. This involves calculating the setFillPatternOffset and the setFillPatternScale since the dimensions of a regular polygon are relative to the center. There is no clear documentation that I can find regarding the reference point for the fill image, nor whether the scaling factor should use the radius as a proxy for the width and height ratios or not. The following code results in a misplaced image on the polygon. Anyone know what the alignment rules are for fillPatternImage?

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var whex = hexagon.getRadius() * 2;
    var xratio = whex / imageObj.width;  
    var yratio = whex / imageObj.height;

    hexagon.setFillPatternImage(imageObj);
    hexagon.setFillPatternOffset(-whex/2,-whex/2);
    hexagon.setFillPatternScale( [ xratio, yratio ] );
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was over-thinking this. Rather than using the width of the destination polygon when setting the offset, kineticjs handles the scaling of that offset for you. As a result you simply set the offset with:

```js
hexagon.setFillPatternOffset(-imageObj.width/2, -imageObj.height/2);
```